# NemakiWare "CMIS Exception: permissionDenied"

Tags: cmis

I'm trying to create new CMIS type using Workbench and always get the message:
"CMIS Exception: permissionDenied".

Does anybody has experience with NemakiWare how to solve this problem?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you made sure you're connecting as a user that's allowed to create new types in your system?

Comment: Also, not all CMIS repositories support type mutability.

Comment: I tried to create custom type as user "admin", using CMIS Workbench.

Comment: The error message by NemakiWare is quite diffrenet as by others CMIS repositories that do not support type mutability, like Alfresco or Nuxeo. There was the Error message " not supported" and by NemakiWare is the problem with permissions, although I'm using "admin".

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this misleading message using a different CMIS-compliant repository (Alfresco) when referencing a deprecated link structure for the CMIS endpoint.

i.e., older versions of Alfresco provide an AtomPub endpoint like this:

```
http://cms.mysite.com/alfresco/cmisatom
```

Newer versions implement this structure:

```
http://cms.mysite.com/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.0/atom
```

If I attempted to access the former link, I'd get an "access denied" message. Make sure your endpoint fits the structure appropriate to the version of NemakiWare you're running.